# after early return does next code execute

Tags: php, return

I have php file where i use if statments and i call this file via ajax.. onSuccess it gives me result if file is upload successfully or error.

Code look like this:

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    return "no image was selected";
}
if($two_many_images){
    return "Only x images are alowed to upload";
}
if($size>2014522){
    return "Size error";
}
foreach($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'] as $key=>$imgLocation){ 
    uploadImage($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'][$key], $imgLocation);
}
```

Question : In first if statment condition is true, wil my second if statment  execute ?

Comment: no, return exits execution in that scope, ( function / method )

Comment: Because after return type every thing is vanished

Comment: so you mean my second condition won't execute ?

Comment: That is correct, if return is hit, it is returned to where it called from.  Think of it like a pointer, if you call a function you send the pointer into that function, when it hits a return, the pointer returns to the line where the function was called and runs on from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily demonstrated, for example you have a function:

```
funciton foo(){
    echo "foo\n";
    return;
    echo 'bar';
}
```

if you call

```
foo();
```

It will print out

```
foo
```

But not `bar`.  Once execution pointer hits the return it will return back to where `foo()` was called from.  This can also be easily shown.

```
foo();
foo();
foo();
```

Prints

```
foo
foo
foo
```

UPDATE: based off your comments the correct way to do what you want is this

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    echo "no image was selected";
    exit();
}
if($two_many_images){
    echo "Only x images are alowed to upload";
    exit();
}
if($size>2014522){
    echo "Size error";
    exit();
}
foreach($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'] as $key=>$imgLocation){ 
    uploadImage($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['tmp_name'][$key], $imgLocation);
}
```

I use `exit()` instead of return, because it's more readable and makes more sense, even though in your case return has the same effect.  Exit will completely end execution for php, which is really what you want.  You could also do something like

```
die( 'Message' );
```

Or

```
exit( 'Message' );
```

As well which will exit and output the message.  They are all pretty much the same...  I put `echo` first just because it always feels a bit dirty to me to put stuff in exit.  Not sure why that is, maybe it I link it to unintended behavior because of seeing die() so much at the top of files not meant to be ran outside of framework.  But I digress.

Just for the sake of completeness, based of your comments, if you call return from the global scope in PHP, it has no where to return to so execution just halts at that point.  The reason it's better to use exit or die is that return has distinctly different behavior, which is to 'return' data from a function call. So it's more readable to use the method who's behavior best matches what you want.  That being to end execution of the current script ( PHP instance ).

Comment: in function  i tested it works like you said but i ask about whole file

Comment: it just ends executing, You wont get the response of the return in that case, you need to `echo` it out first and then do `return`;

Comment: Wow a down vote? really? I mean seriously.  You could at least put the reason for the downvote, does this not answer the question. In fact I went beyond just that, and provided best practice advice.

Comment: @Aryan - I know you didn't, someone else had.  As far as up voting, no a problem, just happy I was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

No, your second statement will not be executed. When the return is invoked, the rest of the code will not be executed. The PHP documentation says:

> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended.